# Add images in NSAttributedString and save to Core Data peformance

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nsattributedstring

I'm encountering this huge performance issue while saving the NSAttrbutedString with images in it to Core Data.

[image: CoreData Schema]

There is a UITextView where allows the user to input text as well as adding images. When user finishes typing and click '**done**' button, it will be saved to CoreData, and shows in a TableView.

**Here is how I save the content when click 'done' button:**

Create a private MOC and assign the AppDelegates managedObjectContext as its parent MOC.

```
privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateMOC.parent = managedObjectContext

privateMOC.perform {
    do {
      try self.privateMOC.save()

      self.managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
        do {
          try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
          fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
      }
    } catch {
      print("Could not save \(error)")
    }
  }
```

There are two issues:

1. Depends on the images, when I click 'done' button, the UI is blocked and takes 3 - 5 seconds before the view dismissed and shown in the TableView.
2. I check the actual database .sqlite and found, one single newly-added entry(text and images in UITextView) makes the database size increases almost **12MB**! (Maybe the images take too much space?)

Any suggestions how to tackle these issues?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These issues are going to be difficult to prevent in your use case. By using `NSCoding` on an `NSAttributedString` that includes images, what you're asking for is a binary blob where you can't control the encoding process in any way.

- It might be that the image size is inflated, e.g. because you're saving the uncompressed data instead of a PNG or JPEG. But you can't do anything about that because you can't control how `NSAttributedString` handles it. So you're probably stuck with the large data size.
- The long processing time is probably connected to the previous point-- you can't control what `NSAttributedString` is doing internally, but it's likely that a lot of that time is taken up dealing with the image(s).

You might improve on the save time if you encoded the attributed strings on your own instead of using a transformable attribute. Then you could start the encoding in advance, in the background, instead of having it happen when you're saving data. You probably can't fix the encoding time, but you may be able to make it happen earlier and be less noticeable. I think you're stuck with the size as long as you're using encoded attributed strings, though.

I don't know what your app is doing but if you could get away from potentially massive `NSAttributedString`s you'll avoid the problems you're having.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explain! You are right! The size of the image is huge (~13MB) without any compression. And I was trying to save the raw image.

origin image width : 2448.0  
origin image height : 3264.0  
origin Image size in bytes:13532006(~**13MB**!)  
after compress image width : Optional(750.0)  
after compress image height : Optional(1000.0)  
after compress Image size in bytes:908975 (**~900kb**)  

After compression, it's much faster. However, it still blocks the UI while saving the context. How could I save it in the background without blocking my UI?

Comment: I was thinking that with a binary Core Data attribute instead of transformable, you'd have to call the `NSCoding` methods yourself. You could do that before attempting to save changes, in a background queue. You'd probably use `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to decode.

Comment: Thanks! The thing is the content is set to transformable, and I don't have the option to change it to binary. Because otherwise I'll have to do a database migration to convert all the previous content to binary (I did a migration before and it was such a pain, and many users even lost their data :( ).

Comment: I might be too late to answer this, but I had run into a similar issue where my UI was being blocked for 3 to 5 seconds when I was trying to save managedContext. The issue was that I was trying to save inside performAndWait() block. I changed it to perform() block and it just worked fine. If you don't need performAndWait() then you can try changing it.