# Get UIImage and text from NSAttributed string in Swift 4

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I want to create a note like an app in `iOS`. I have added text and image successfully on `UITextView` and got an attributed string with `NSTextAttachment`. I have saved this attributed string in database with a field type "Varchar". But After fetching data back from the database I am not able to get text and image back from this attributed string.

this my sample code:

```
var imagesArray = [Any]()
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: textView.attributedText.length), options: [], using: {(value,range,stop) -> Void in
            if (value is NSTextAttachment) {
                let attachment: NSTextAttachment? = (value as? NSTextAttachment)
                var image: UIImage? = nil

                if ((attachment?.image) != nil) {
                    image = attachment?.image
                } else {
                    image = attachment?.image(forBounds: (attachment?.bounds)!, textContainer: nil, characterIndex: range.location)
                }

                if image != nil {
                    imagesArray.append(image!)
                }
            }
        })
```

here the "`value`" always returns nil.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I recognize my code (well I didn't do the Swift converted version). "I have saved this attributed string in database with a field type "Varchar" I think that's where lies your issue. How do you save it exactly? The attached images are saved too? I've read question with issue about saving the `NSTextAttachment` linked with the `NSAttributedString`, I'd tend to guess that where is your issue, not in that code.

Comment: @Larme no I haven't save image in database. I just append uiimage with NSTextAttachment and then insert as uitextview's attributed string. I am confused how can I manage this. Do I need to save image in database separately ?? or it will work with nsattributed string ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454065/add-images-in-nsattributedstring-and-save-to-core-data-peformance ?

Comment: @Larme I have checked this link.. Still I am confused.. 

this is my attributed string: